# Scale factors for fft2/ifft2 changing size of matrix in-between

Tags: matlab, fft

Because of optimizations I change the size of my matrix when in the frequency domain. I'm not sure how to compensate with the scale factors. Currently I do it like this but I'm not certain it's correct:

```
B1 = fft2(A1)/numel(A1);
B2 = B1(idx1, idx2); %Cut out some parts of B1
A2 = fft2(B2); %I want the sign change
```

Does this scale properly? If so, please show.

EDIT: Changed multiplication with numel to division

Answer (score 2):

If your apply `fft` and `ifft` sequentially, you may not worry about scaling, they are going to compensate each other meaning `ifft(fft(A))` equals exactly `A`. But in your case, when the size is changed, just do

```
B1 = fft2(A1);
B2 = B1(idx1, idx2);
A2 = numel(B2)/numel(B1)*ifft2(B2);
```

Note, in the code, you have shown above, you did not apply the inverse Fourier transform second time, that might cause an error.

Comment: Can you explain the scaling? I'm quite confused what kind of scaling fft2 and ifft2 does.

The reason I used fft2 is because that corresponds to the real problem I'm solving where the signs should flip (imaging equation).